# swift NSURL, "cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL" into array

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, nsurl

Help! Total Swift Newb! 
I think I'm so close, but my non-experience holds me back..

How can I make this line into an array like those above it?

```
// NEED HELP HERE~!
cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: mediaURL)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
```

Please excuse my chopped up code; just too messy to paste completely.

```
class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate, MWFeedParserDelegate, SideBarDelegate {
var feedItems = [MWFeedItem]()

// xml parser
var myParser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()

// rss records
var rssRecordList : [RssRecord] = [RssRecord]()
var rssRecord : RssRecord?

// original var before adding media
//    var isTagFound = [ "item": false , "title":false, "pubDate": false ,"link":false]
var isTagFound = [ "item": false , "title":false, "pubDate": false , "media": false , "link":false]

var mediaURL = ""



////SNIP MESSY CODE

//return the number of rows
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.rssRecordList.count
    return feedItems.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell

    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem?
    cell.itemTitleLabel.text = item?.title

    let thisRecord : RssRecord  = self.rssRecordList[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemDateLabel.text = thisRecord.pubDate

    // NEED HELP HERE~!
    cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: mediaURL)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

print("print check for URL",mediaURL)



////SNIP MESSY CODE

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if elementName == "item" {
        mediaURL = ""
        self.isTagFound["item"] = true
        self.rssRecord = RssRecord()

    }else if elementName == "title" {
        self.isTagFound["title"] = true

    }else if elementName == "pubDate" {
        self.isTagFound["pubDate"] = true

    }else if elementName == "media:thumbnail" {
        self.mediaURL = attributeDict["url"]!
    }
}
```

When I "print(mediaURL)" I can see the URL of the last "media:thumbnail" asset from the RSS, so know I am close..
I'm sure this is a syntax issue if anyone could help!

Thank you in advance, and to Michael for his good questions.

To answer Michael, I added the part of the NSXMLParser with the part that sets the "mediaURL" along with what classes I'm calling at top.

Also, I am trying to read the "mediaURL" out of an array as he questioned.
The array would be of the rows of feeds of an RSS that holds "media:thumbnail" URL values.

Apologies again that this is so chopped up. You can see I've patched this together with both  MWFeedParserDelegate and NSXMLParserDelegate code I found here-there.

Thank you again!

~~~ UPDATE ~~~
So being too new to Swift and Objective-C, I could not understand how to work this. However, I did find a different example and it looks like it lines up what Himanshu was trying to say:

```
    func loadImageSynchronouslyFromURLString(_ urlString: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.timeoutInterval = 30.0
        var response: URLResponse?
        let error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
        var data: Data?
        do {
            data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning: &response)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error??.pointee = error1
            data = nil
        }
        if (data != nil) {
            return UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope someone else might benefit something from this..

Comment: This question needs more detail: where does `mediaURL` come from?  I don't see it anywhere else in your code snippet up there.  Also, WHAT are you trying to put into an array?  Are you trying to read something *out* of an array (e.g. the `mediaURL`)?  which array?

Comment: Updated to try and make better sense with Michael Dautermann's good questions!

Comment: @swiftnewb check my answer

Comment: Thank you Himanshu, but being such a newb, I could not syntax it properly.
Finally, I upgraded to xcode 8, and found a different example that helped.

For reference, I added below original, the new image calls.

Answer (score 0):

**create one funcation for get image from url**

```
func getImageFromURL(_ fileURL: String) -> UIImage {
    var url = NSURL(string: fileURL)!
    var image = UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))!
    return image
}
```

**and just simple call it**

```
self.imageview.image! = self.getImageFromURL(url)
```

**OR**

**try this code its work with some library Kingfisher**

```
let url = NSURL(string: URL STRING HERE )!
[YOURIMAGEVIEW sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLACEHOLDERIMAGE"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
       if (!error) {
             YOURIMAGEVIEW.image=image;
        }
 }];
```

You can use **Kingfisher** library for download image and set into your UIImageview.